# preg_rlike not matching characters like ò , í , è etc

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-udf

Can you hep me to match special characters like `ò , í , è` with mysql preg_rlike

```
select first_name from authors where preg_rlike('/Jòse/i',authors.first_name);
```

It will not retrieve data even if the database has value.

We can handle this with `LIKE` but I have many like `Jòse|Jose|James`

Let me please know how can we handle this.

Comment: Are you saying that you _don't_ want to treat accented vowels different than none accented vowels, or are you asking something else?

Comment: Is field `first_name` has Collation: `utf8_general_ci`, then can you try `select first_name from authors where like '%Jòse%';`

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen the query in my description is not retrieving data, even if the table has values with first_name as Jòse

Comment: Oh sorry, it will work if our table is UTF8 encoded.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Are you using lib_mysqludf_preg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments

I got answer to this question either by making the table or just that field is UT8 encoded or using CONVERT(field_name USING utf8) in the query